# Javascript: how do i load all the links in the html to the same window one after another in an interval of a few seconds

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript: how to open a page then wait for few seconds open another page in the same window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133075/javascript-how-to-open-a-page-then-wait-for-few-seconds-open-another-page-in-th)

I tried to load all the links in the html to the same window. However only the first link gets loaded. I got an error message saying webpage undefined in Chrome. Can someone please help me because i am pretty new in Javascript. Thanks. The code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

window.onload=function(){myFunction()};

function myFunction()
{
var links = document.links;

mywin=window.open("","mywindow");
mywin.location=links[0];
for(var i = 1; i < links.length; i++)
{
    setTimeout(function(){mywin.location=links[i];},5000);
} 
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">yahoo</a></h1>
<h1><a href="http://www.youtube.com">youtube</a></h1>
<h1><a href="http://www.google.com">google</a></h1>
</body>
</html
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not opening the pages in intervals. The for loop will put run the setTimeout in quick succession, which the content will run after 5 seconds in very quick successions. The For loop will cycle through very fast, maybe taken a few ms in between each loop. So the function in setTimeout will start firing after 5 seconds, but with only a few ms in between each call.

Secondly, the loop increment i to 3 in the end in your case. When the function is actually called.

```
mywin.location=links[i];
```

The i is actually 3, which result in undefined.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function myFunction()
{
    var links = document.links;

    function open(win, i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            win.location = links[i];
            if(i+1 < links.length) {
                open(win, i+1);
            }
        }, 5000);
    }

    mywin=window.open("","mywindow");
    mywin.location=links[0];
    open(mywin, 1);
}
```

If you would like to write `open` outside of `myFunction` you need to pass `links` as a third argument too.

EDIT:
And probably you don't initialize `mywin` variable anywhere. Put `var` before it, otherwise it pollutes `window` object.

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried out and it works. However, I tried to pass links as a third argument and put open function outside myFunction it doesn't work, but it's ok. Thanks again